# Summary and plot after MatchIt with only some covariates

Tags: r, matching

Is there anyway to report the balance of only some covariate after MatchIt?
I am using matchit with exact matching based on a factor variable for locations that contains many values. Something like this

```
m.out <- matchit(formula = y ~  x1 + x2,
                  data = D, 
                  method = "nearest",
                  exact = ~ location )
```

After using `plot(summary(m.out))` I get many rows that all are balanced and I want to skip them from the plot. I also tried `cobalt::love.plot(m.out)`, but couldn't find any option to drop some covariate in the graph. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cobalt`, you can use the `formula` method as follows:

```
cobalt::love.plot(y ~ x1 + x2, data = D, weights = get.w(m.out))
```

Because you control which covariates are used, you don't have to display the covariates you don't want.

In `MatchIt`, one hacky way to do this would be to manually remove those variables from the `matchit` object. That is, you could run

```
m.out$X[c("location")] <- NULL
```

before running `summary()` and the `location` variable will be removed from the output.

Comment: That works, thanks!